# Node Version Manager install - nvm command not found

Tags: node.js, terminal, nvm

I am trying to install NVM as per these [instructions](http://academy.appgyver.com/courses/2/lessons/32)

I typed in this command in terminal:

```
$ curl https://raw.github.com/creationix/nvm/master/install.sh | sh
```

After running the install, I restart the terminal and attempt to install Node.js with this command:

```
$ nvm install 0.8
```

but I get the response:

```
-bash: nvm: command not found
```

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Additional Info:

I've been looking around for solutions from other posts and forums. I found another solution using

```
$ git clone git://github.com/creationix/nvm.git ~/.nvm
```

but this times out every time I attempt that.

Comment: restarting the terminal worked for me

Answer (score 648, accepted):

Check your `.bash_profile`,  `.zshrc`, or `.profile` file. You most likely had a problem during the installation.

You should have the following at the end of one of those files.

```
[[ -s $HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh ]] && . $HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh  # This loads NVM
```

The `. $HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh` is the same as `source $HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh`

See: [Sourcing a File](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x237.html)

You can also check to see if you have a `.nvm` folder.

```
ls -a | grep .nvm
```

If you're missing that folder then the installation failed to run the git command. This could be due to being behind a proxy. Try running the following instead.

```
git clone http://github.com/creationix/nvm.git .nvm
```

Comment: I do have that line at the end of my .bash_profile file. But I am missing the .nvm file. I'm guessing the missing file is the problem?

Comment: The `.nvm` should be a directory. It's installed via the following command `git clone git://github.com/creationix/nvm.git $NVM_TARGET`. You said previously that you tried to run that command yourself and it failed? Most likely you are behind a proxy and are not configured probably. Try running the follow instead. `git clone http://github.com/creationix/nvm.git .nvm`

Comment: Looks like I do have the .nvm directory. I also have the needed line in the .bash_profile file.

Comment: also have the line, but 'source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh' works

Comment: If the .nvm folder is empty it's probably because fetching of the repo has failed due to xcode agreement license not been accepted. Running `sudo xcodebuild -license` and accepting the license (by pushing `space` for reaching the end of the license and to agree to its terms) does the trick.

Comment: You may also need to `source .bashrc` or `source .profile` depending

Comment: Where and how do I find the file .bash_profile or .profile?

Comment: Almost always those files will exists in your home dir. `source $HOME/.bashrc`, etc.

Comment: put nvm configs in `.zshrc` help me to solve it. thanks

Comment: Nothing but `.zshrc` worked for me.

Comment: I also had to change the [ -z "$PS1" ] && return to [ "$CI" == "true" ] || ( [ -z "$PS1" ] && return ) line to make the .bashrc work in case it is launched in gitlab CI environment

Comment: I restarted bash before trying this solution, and it worked!

Answer (score 1797):

I think you missed this step:

```
source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
```

You can run this command on the bash OR you can put it in the file `/.bashrc` or `~/.profile` or `~/.zshrc` to automatically load it

https://github.com/creationix/nvm

Comment: Let's make the documentation better. I've created an issue on the nvm repo: https://github.com/creationix/nvm/issues/748

Comment: I executed this manually multiple times until I finally put it in my .bashrc!

Comment: this worked for me but in order to automate it i had to create profile first. "touch ~/.profile", "open ~/.profile" ,  paste above, save+ close.  works in new windows now

Comment: `nvm`, `node`, and `npm` where working without this. Now, for some reason, I have to do this or those commands aren't found. Why wasn't this necessary before but is now?

Comment: Adding it to `~/.bash_profile` was what worked for me

Comment: This was the missing line that worked for me.. I spent hours trying to figure out how to fix the permission errors i was getting when trying to deploy my firebase cloud function.. if you're stuck on permission errors - id suggest uninstalling node and then re installing the nvm - AND don't forget this line of code you'll need it.. thanks... - site that helped me uninstall it - https://stackabuse.com/how-to-uninstall-node-js-from-mac-osx/

Comment: This worked for me. I added `source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh` to my `~/.zshrc` and now `nvm` works every time

Comment: I tried this, but for some reason when reopening a bash, I had the same problem. I did what the following link suggests: https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/issues/2060 and it worked well for me. I hope this could help. Thx

Comment: I would assume this to run itself after the installation?? This is so weird but thank you for saving tons of time looking for other tweaks!

Comment: The docs for installing NodeJS on WSL2 don't mention anything about this command, but that command worked for me. Thank you! https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/nodejs/setup-on-wsl2

Comment: OMG! This is crazy! In the GIT install instructions, there's no mention of this source. It took me days to resolve docker dependencies, while the actual problem was THIS source! Thank YOU!!!

Comment: In my case, the folder ~/.nvm/ did not contain any files, so i put nvm.sh in there and now everything is working

Comment: reinstall brew right after this `brew reinstall nvm`

Comment: this work for MacOs

Comment: This must be marked as unswer

Comment: If someone get stuck, how to & where to create these files `/.bashrc or ~/.profile or ~/.zshrc` to them, just create a file  `touch ~/.profile` then to edit the file in console `nano ~/.profile` or you can edit the file manually from this directory `C:\Users\<your username>`  and then paste `source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh` save the file. It worked for me.

Comment: wish I could upvote multiple times for when I find the same answer again and again :D

Comment: This still does not work 2024 putting in ~/.zhsrc does not work

Answer (score 250):

This works for me:

1. Before installing `nvm`, run this in terminal: `touch ~/.bash_profile`
2. After, run this in terminal:
   `curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.1/install.sh | bash`
3. **Important...** - DO NOT forget to *Restart* your terminal **OR** use command `source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh` (this will refresh the available commands in your system path).
4. In the terminal, use command `nvm --version` and you should see the version

Comment: 3) Don't forget to Restart your terminal
Key component! That's why mine wasn't working. Thanks

Comment: Works! and, Don't forget to Restart your terminal Key component!

Answer (score 112):

### Quick answer

Figure out the following:

1. Which shell is your terminal using, type in: `echo $0` to find out (normally works)
2. Which start-up file does that shell load when starting up **(NOT *login shell starting file*, the normal *shell starting file*, there is a difference!)**
3. Add `source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh` to that file (assuming that file exists at that location, it is the default install location)
4. Start a new terminal session
5. Profit?

### Example

As you can see it states `zsh` and not `bash`.
[image]

To fix this I needed to add `source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh` to the `~/.zshrc` file as when starting a new terminal my Deepin Terminal zsh reads `~/.zshrc` and not bashs `~/.bashrc`.

### Why does this happen

This happens because when installing NVM it adds code to `~/.bashrc`, as my terminal Deepin Terminal uses `zsh` and not `bash` it never reads `~/.bashrc` and therefor never loads NVM.

**In other words: this is NVMs fault.**

More on `zsh` can be read on one of the answers [here](https://superuser.com/questions/187639/zsh-not-hitting-profile).

### Quick answer for zsh users

```
curl raw.github.com/creationix/nvm/master/install.sh | zsh
```

Comment: you can simply put zsh at the end of the curl command.
eg: curl https://raw.github.com/creationix/nvm/master/install.sh | zsh

Comment: This was totally my issue because OSX Catalina uses zsh by default now, not bash.

Comment: @Prabhakar thanks for pointing out the zsh keyword at the end of the curl command. it worked for me

Comment: works for me: 
1) curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.34.0/install.sh | zsh
2) close current terminal and open a new one
3) you can use nvm!

Comment: Quick answer for zsh users - worked for me thank you

Comment: reinstall brew right after this `brew reinstall nvm`

Comment: phenomenally save hours of my basic confusion with Terminal's version with the command 'echo $0'

Comment: Note that nvm is explicitly unsupported when installed through homebrew; please only use the install script in nvm's readme.

Additionally, do NOT install from master; master is often broken - only install from a tagged version release.

Answer (score 85):

`source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh` Add this line to ~/.bashrc, ~/.profile, or ~/.zshrc

Comment: this is the "permanant" solution that lasts across multiple shells or shell sessions.

Comment: This is the only answer that will work. Even after multiple re openings of terminal. Lastly, do not forget to restart your terminal once you do this :)

Comment: like this? `source ~/.bashrc/nvm.sh `

Answer (score 55):

All answers to this questions are useful. Especially the answer given by Travis helped me. For Mac OS X users I would like to provide some steps which will help them to work with the fresh installation of Node Version Manager a.k.a. nvm.

**Installing & using nvm on Mac OS X**

Here are the steps for fresh installation of nvm and using it without any issue:

- Install homebrew from [here](https://brew.sh/).
- Using homebrew install nvm

  `brew update
  brew install nvm`
- Create `.nvm` directory at `~/.nvm` location.

  `mkdir ~/.nvm`
- Now if you don't have `.bash_profile` file setup for OS X terminal then please create a `.bash_profile` at the root level:

  `nano ~/.bash_profile`
- Paste below code in the `.bash_profile` and press `CTRL + O` and press enter to save `.bash_profile` file. Press `CTRL + X` to exit from editor:

  `export NVM_DIR=~/.nvm
   source $(brew --prefix nvm)/nvm.sh`
- Now either quite (`CMD + Q`) the terminal or run below command to load `.bash_profile` settings:

  `source ~/.bash_profile`
- Now run `nvm ls` command to get the list of all installed nodejs versions.

Comment: Thank you, I think that what missed for me was creating the `.nvm` directory.

Comment: It also can work for zash if repace ~/.bash_profile with ~/.zshrc

Comment: Nice and complete answer, following these steps, solves my issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 40):

I faced a similar issue when installing **nvm** on a **MacBook Pro**.

I had installed **nvm** initially using brew:

```
brew install nvm
```

But when I run the command:

```
nvm --version
```

I get the error:

> zsh nvm: command not found

**Here's how I fixed it**:

Installing `nvm` using **brew** is not enough to get it to work. You also need to do the following below;

- Confirm that the source `~/.zshrc`, `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.profile`, or `~/.bashrc` file exists:

  ```
  zsh: ~/.zshrc

  bash: ~/.bashrc

  ksh: ~/.profile
  ```

  Else create it using:

  ```
  touch ~/.zshrc

  touch ~/.bashrc

  touch ~/.profile
  ```
- Next, run either of the commands below:

  **Note**: You can check the referenced link below to get the updated commands.

  ```
  curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.1/install.sh | bash
  ```

  OR

  ```
  wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.1/install.sh | bash
  ```

  **Note**:  Running either of the above commands downloads a script and runs it. The script clones the `nvm` repository to `~/.nvm`, and attempts to add the source lines from the snippet below to the correct profile file (`~/.bash_profile`, `~/.zshrc`, `~/.profile`, or `~/.bashrc`)

  ```
  export NVM_DIR="$([ -z "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME-}" ] && printf %s "${HOME}/.nvm" || printf %s "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME}/nvm")"
  [ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" # This loads nvm.
  ```

You can check the referenced link below to get the updated script.

**Reference**: [Installing and Updating NVM](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#installing-and-updating)

Comment: I followed https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#troubleshooting-on-macos

Comment: Not working on  mac ..

Comment: Thanks, it works now. I couldn't install Node version 14 with nvm on my Mac M2 Air, but it's working fine now. Also I upgraded my git version

Comment: THIS STILL DOES NOT WORK!!!!

Answer (score 30):

In macOS, i had to source it using `source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh` command to fix this problem.

After that, add these lines

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" # This loads nvm
```

onto `~/.bash_profile` so that nvm will be sourced automatically upon login.

Answer (score 29):

Assuming that you have installed nvm using brew (I am on a mac), I mean something like `brew install nvm`, all you need to do is:

```
 1. You should create NVM's working directory if it doesn't exist:

  mkdir ~/.nvm

 2. Add the following to ~/.zshrc or your desired shell configuration
    file:

      export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
      [ -s "/usr/local/opt/nvm/nvm.sh" ] && . "/usr/local/opt/nvm/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
      [ -s "/usr/local/opt/nvm/etc/bash_completion.d/nvm" ] && . "/usr/local/opt/nvm/etc/bash_completion.d/nvm"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
```

Comment: Same info at https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#troubleshooting-on-macos

Comment: This drastically increases the load time of my terminal, anyone else experiencing this?

Answer (score 23):

Same problem encountered. You have to source shell file as well as change nvm's default version.

First, `source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh`.

Second, change nvm's default version.

```
nvm alias default 16.14.2
```

If you don't change nvm's default version, you will find the node version stay the same when you switch to another iTerm tab.

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful and fixed my issue. I didn't have to check the default version though as I didn't have it. 
default -> 16.14.2 (-> N/A)

Answer (score 22):

**OSX 10.15.0 [Catalina](https://www.howtogeek.com/439830/whats-new-in-macos-10.15-catalina-available-fall-2019/) (released November 2019) changed the default shell to zsh.**

The default shell was previously bash.

The installation command given on the [nvm GitHub page](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#troubleshooting-on-macos) needs to be tweaked to include "zsh" at the end.

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/master/install.sh | zsh
```

Note: you might need to ensure the `.rc` file for zsh is present beforehand:

```
touch ~/.zsrhrc
```

Comment: Just a small correction as I was initially tripped up by the file name. It's `touch ~/.zshrc` :) Otherwise can verify the above works

Comment: Adding the .zsrhrc even works with Homebrew. It's in the README.md file under the Troubleshooting on macOS

Answer (score 20):

I have the same problem and what saved my life is the sentence "you may have to add to more than one of  your "~/.bashrc, ~/.profile, or ~/.zshrc files". the following lines were in my .bashrc only, I added it to files ".bash_profile" and ".profile" and worked for me .

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
```

Comment: I tried this and even created the .profile with no luck.

Comment: agh! I just had to restart the terminal! Thanks!

Comment: Yes, restart the terminal or run the following in the corresponding shell:
bash: `source ~/.bashrc`
zsh: `source ~/.zshrc`
ksh: `. ~/.profile`

Comment: After a lot of research on this for days. Finally only this worked for me!. I had this only on .zshrc before. After adding it in all the other files mentioned by @ahmdGeek It started running. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 17):

First add following lines in ~/.bashrc file

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
```

then open terminal and source the nvm.sh script

```
source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
```

Answer (score 12):

For MacOS;

Run on Terminal >

```
open ~/.bash_profile
```

Paste all of this=

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" # This loads nvm
```

Answer (score 10):

1. Open terminal
2. if you have zsh terminal then type command 'open ~/.zshrc'
3. Add end of file and save the following:
   source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh

Comment: Wasted an hour of my life. Thanks for this!

Comment: How is this working for you guys? It's not working at all for me!!!

Answer (score 9):

Over time, nvm (from homebrew) changed its post-installation instructions.

I was getting `nvm_find_nvmrc not found` on a new computer, until I replaced

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
```

with

```
[ -s "/opt/homebrew/opt/nvm/nvm.sh" ] && \. "/opt/homebrew/opt/nvm/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "/opt/homebrew/opt/nvm/etc/bash_completion.d/nvm" ] && \. "/opt/homebrew/opt/nvm/etc/bash_completion.d/nvm"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
```

which properly found the installation location.

Answer (score 8):

For Mac OS:

1. Open Terminal
2. Run `touch ~/.bash_profile`
3. Run `vi ~/.bash_profile`
4. Type `source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh`
5. Press `Shift + Esc` and type `wq` and press `enter`
6. Done.

Comment: In ubuntu 18.04, I only needed:
4. Type source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh and thank you much!

Answer (score 6):

If you are using OS X, you might have to create your .bash_profile file before running the installation command. That did it for me.

Create the profile file

```
touch ~/.bash_profile
```

Re-run the install and you'll see a relevant line in the output this time.

> => Appending source string to /Users/{username}/.bash_profile

Reload your profile (or close/re-open the Terminal window).

```
.  ~/.bash_profile
```

Answer (score 6):

Not directly connected to the question, but there is a similar problem that may happen, take a look at this question: [Can't execute nvm from new bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31012710/cant-execute-nvm-from-new-bash)

---

**Here's my answer on that post, just for the reference:**

If you are running from a new bash instance, and you HAVE the initialization code at your ~/.bashrc, ~/.bash_profile, etc, then you need to check this initialization file for conditionals.

On Ubuntu 14, there is a:

```
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac
```

At line 6, that will halt it's execution if bash is not being ran with the "-i" (interactive) flag. So you would need to run:

```
bash -i
```

Also, at the end of the file, there is a

```
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return
```

That will halt it's execution if not being ran with $PS1 set (like on a remote ssh session).

If you do not wish to add any env vars or flags, you will need to remove those conditionals from your initialization file.

Hope that's helpful.

Answer (score 6):

For Mac OS:

1. Open Terminal
2. Check if you have .profile file with this command:

> ls -a ~/

3. If you havnt this file just create one:

> touch ~/.profile

3. Add this command to .profile file :

> source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh

4. Press Shift + Esc and type wq and press enter

Comment: just adding the source worked for me

Answer (score 5):

Add the following lines to the files `~/.bashrc` and `~/.bash_profile` :

```
# NVM changes
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"
```

and restart the terminal or do `source ~/.bashrc` or `source ~/.bash_profile`. If you need command completion for nvm then also add the line:

```
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"
```

Along with the above lines to `~/.bashrc` and `~/.bash_profile`.

Answer (score 5):

For the issue was fixed when I moved

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
```

to the end of `.zshrc`

Answer (score 2):

I had fixed this problem.

1. touch ~/.bash_profile
2. open  ~/.bash_profile
3. paste`export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
   [ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
   [ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion`

Answer (score 2):

In `Windows 8.1 x64` same happened with me, and received the following message.

> nvm install 8.3.0 bash: nvm: command not found windows

So, follow or verify below following steps-

first install `coreybutler/nvm-windows` from `github.com`. Currently available latest release 1.1.5 `nvm-setup.zip`, later extracted the setup `nvm-setup.exe` and install as following locations:

```
NVM_HOME    : C:\Users\Administrator\nvm
NVM_SYMLINK : C:\Program Files\nodejs
```

and meanwhile setup will manage the environment variable to `Path` as above said for you.

Now *run `Git Bash` as Administrator* and then.

```
$ nvm install 8.3.0 all

Downloading node.js version 8.3.0 (64-bit)...
Complete
Creating C:\Users\Administrator\nvm\temp

Downloading npm version 5.3.0... Complete
Installing npm v5.3.0...

Installation complete. If you want to use this version, type

nvm use 8.3.0

$ nvm use 8.3.0
Now using node v8.3.0 (64-bit)
```

here run your command without using prefix `$`, it is just shown here to determine it as a command line and now we will verify the nvm version.

```
$ nvm --version
Running version 1.1.5.

Usage:
-----------------------
```

if you have problem using `nvm` to install `node`, you can see this list of available `nodejs` releases here `https://nodejs.org/download/release/` and choose the correct installer as per your requirement version equal or higher than `v6.3.0` directly.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem, but this worked for me:

Since macOS 10.15, the default shell is zsh and nvm will look for `.zshrc` to update, none is installed by default. Create one with touch `~/.zshrc` and run the install script again.

more info here: [Troubleshooting on macOS](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#troubleshooting-on-macos)

Answer (score 2):

After spending more than 3 hours testing some of the solutions above I came across an answer that was working for me.
I am under Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS and with a fresh install added the official command:

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.38.0/install.sh | 
bash
```

The problem was that my version of curl was obtained via snap. Removing it and re-installing it as suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67696432/installing-nvm-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts) fixed the issue:

```
sudo snap remove curl
sudo apt install curl
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.38.0/install.sh 
| bash
nvm install node
```

Answer (score 1):

The nvm install script by default adds initialization code to your `$HOME/.profile`, which is only loaded by a login shell (in a desktop environment you may never see a login shell).

The nvm command in your login shell is not propagated to sub-shells (like console windows and IDE terminals after you log in).  This snippet in your `$HOME/.bashrc` will only load nvm if it is an interactive shell and has not been loaded already

```
# if nvm dir is not set and the standard nvm directory exists
if [ -z "$NVM_DIR" -a -d "$HOME/.nvm" ] ; then
# set nvm dir
  export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
fi

# if nvm dir is set and this shell is interactive
if [ -d "$NVM_DIR" -a -n "$PS1" ] ; then
  # if nvm command is not defined
  if ! type -t nvm >/dev/null ; then
    # set it
    source "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"
  fi
fi
```

Putting this in your `$HOME/.bashrc` file will fix the missing nvm problem in interactive bash shells, even from a gui, and even if nvm is installed in a non-standard location.

Answer (score 1):

For me this worked.
First check that the file `.bashrc` has following line

`[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm`

Now `bashrc` is loaded for each terminal session. Thus restart the terminal so that it is loaded again and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

On Debian, as well as adding the below lines to my .bash_profile as one of the above answers said. I also had to open up my terminal preferences (Edit -> Profile Preferences -> Command) and enable 'Run command as a login shell' to get it to work.

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" # This loads nvm
```

Edit: For those on Mac be aware that macOS doesn't read .bashrc on Terminal start, so using .bash_profile is preferable. [See Here.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/13019/239506)

Answer (score 1):

For my case,  it because I use **fish**.  if I not start **fish**, just type nvm will no error now.

Comment: How did you stop the **fish** ?

Comment: type `exit`  @MobileDream.

Answer (score 1):

Use following codes

```
wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.11/install.sh | bash`
source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh`
nvm install 0.8
```

Answer (score 1):

Something to be aware of, which tripped me up for an hour, is that `nvm` is "Implemented as a POSIX-compliant function", as it states at the top of the `nvm.sh` script file. This means there's no `nvm` file in your path, and thus you can't verify that nvm is present using the `which` command. Instead, use `nvm --version`, and verify that you get expected output.

```sh
malderete-ltm:~ malderete$ nvm --version
0.38.0
malderete-ltm:~ malderete$ which nvm
malderete-ltm:~ malderete$ which node
malderete-ltm:~ malderete$ nvm install --lts
Installing latest LTS version.
Downloading and installing node v14.17.5...
Downloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v14.17.5/node-v14.17.5-darwin-x64.tar.xz...
######################################################################### 100.0%
Computing checksum with shasum -a 256
Checksums matched!
Now using node v14.17.5 (npm v6.14.14)
Creating default alias: default -> lts/* (-> v14.17.5)
malderete-ltm:~ malderete$ nvm use --lts
Now using node v14.17.5 (npm v6.14.14)
malderete-ltm:~ malderete$ which node
/Users/malderete/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.5/bin/node
```

(As someone who is only semi-command line literate, I lean on the `which` command by muscle memory. Using `nvm --version` **is** in the instructions, but if you're an idiot like me, you might miss/skip over that part, and use `which nvm` by reflex, and think that nvm isn't installed.)

Comment: I can't believe I'm your first upvote... `which` is also my go-to for determining if I have something... Can't believe it failed me.

Answer (score 1):

Installed nvm using brew. This is what worked for me:

```
    export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
  [ -s "/opt/homebrew/opt/nvm/nvm.sh" ] && \. "/opt/homebrew/opt/nvm/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
  [ -s "/opt/homebrew/opt/nvm/etc/bash_completion.d/nvm" ] && \. "/opt/homebrew/opt/nvm/etc/bash_completion.d/nvm"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It's very similar to previous replies, though, which makes it less helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem recently and sourcing nvm bash script by using source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh resolved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

After trying multiple steps, not sure what was the problem in my case but running this helped:

```
touch ~/.bash_profile
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.32.1/install.sh | bash
```

Verified by `nvm --version`

[image: nvm -v output]

Answer (score 0):

I'm using `linux brew` and `bash` and it asked me to add the following code to `~/.profile`

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
  [ -s "/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/nvm/nvm.sh" ] && \. "/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/nvm/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
  [ -s "/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/nvm/etc/bash_completion.d/nvm" ] && \. "/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/nvm/etc/bash_completion.d/nvm"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
```

But in my case, that did not work.
Instead, adding it to `~/.bashrc` worked.

Answer (score 0):

To overcome the above problem developer need install NVM in his machine to control the nodejs versions. For this we need  to follow the below steps,

1. All nodejs version has to be  uninstalled from the system.
   Install Node version manager
      Download the Node Version Manager from the repository  from Visit https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows#installation--upgrades
2. Install nvm-windows for windows and for other operating system
   find the available pack and install it.
3. If the System is having Admin user then we need to install under Admin user only since nvm will modify Environment variable while installing NodeJS.
4. While installing we have to be very careful about the installation
   folder.It should be under public folder not to any specific user.
   **note :**  This is the one of the problem  NVM could not load in the command prompt or power shell .if you installed NVM in the default location by the installer.
5. Install a version of Nodejs by using the following command.

   **nvm install node-version**

   Example : nvm install 14.3.3

6.To see the versions of Nodejs you have installed on your machine

**nvm list**

7. To use/load a specific version of Nodejs

   **nvm use node-version**

   example :nvm use 14.3.3