# nvm: command not found

Tags: node.js, macos, git, terminal

Good evening. Faced such problem: I'm trying to install node.js, following these instructions https://academy.appgyver.com/installwizard/steps?from=steroids_frontpage_sign_up#/git. But the terminal does not see .nvm command:-(. I tried this [Node Version Manager install - nvm command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16904658/node-version-manager-install-nvm-command-not-found), but I did not find .bash_profile or .profile.

Please, help!
[image]

Comment: Had luck and greater understanding from this Q/A: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16904658/node-version-manager-install-nvm-command-not-found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One may find it easier to follow this tutorial in installing Node.js on a Mac.

http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/installing-node-js-on-osx-10-10-yosemite/

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried this way. Everything is fine but npm install steroids -g does not work in the end(

Comment: @FedorPatutinskiy open a new question with the details