# Can't execute nvm from new bash

Tags: bash, nvm

When I open a new bash, nvm command is not found. It seems that the ~/.nvm/nvm.sh is not being loaded on bash startup.

I have added the line below to ~/.bashrc

```
[[ -s /home/$USER/.nvm/nvm.sh ]] && . /home/$USER/.nvm/nvm.sh
```

Any ideas why it is happening?

Comment: If you run that command manually from the shell session it works correctly and `nvm` becomes available?

Comment: yes, it loads correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running from a new bash instance, and you HAVE the initialization code at your ~/.bashrc, ~/.bash_profile, etc, then you need to check this initialization file for conditionals.

On Ubuntu 14, there is a:

```
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac
```

At line 6, that will halt it's execution if bash is not being ran with the "-i" (interactive) flag. So you would need to run:

```
bash -i
```

Also, at the end of the file, there is a

```
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return
```

That will halt it's execution if not being ran with $PS1 set (like on a remote ssh session).

If you do not wish to add any env vars or flags, you will need to remove those conditionals from your initialization file.

Hope that's helpful.