# -bash: nvm: command not found

Tags: node.js, npm, nvm

When I install nvm using the command wget or curl (OS X El Capitan 10.11.4), the console prints

```
=> nvm is already installed in /Users/weichuang/.nvm, trying to update using git

=> 
=> Source string already in /Users/weichuang/.bashrc
npm ERR! error in /usr/local/lib/node_modules/love: ENOTDIR: not a directory, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/love/package.json'
npm ERR! missing: npmlog@, required by npm-registry-client@7.0.7
npm ERR! missing: prompt@^0.2.14, required by react-native-cli@0.1.4
=> You currently have modules installed globally with `npm`. These will no
=> longer be linked to the active version of Node when you install a new node
=> with `nvm`; and they may (depending on how you construct your `$PATH`)
=> override the binaries of modules installed with `nvm`:

/usr/local/lib
├── commander@2.9.0
├── cordova@5.3.3
├── download-cli@1.0.1
├── express@4.13.3
├── express-generator@4.13.1
├── forever@0.14.1
├── hexo@3.1.1
├── http-server@0.8.5
├── ionic@1.7.14
├── ios-deploy@1.8.2
├── ios-sim@5.0.3
├── JSONStream@1.0.6
├── koa@1.1.2
├──  error: ENOTDIR: not a directory, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/love/package.json
├── marked@0.3.5
├── n@2.0.2
├── node-gyp@3.2.0
├── nw@0.12.3
├── nw-gyp@0.12.4
├── react-native-cli@0.1.4
├── react-tools@0.13.3
├── remem@1.0.3 -> /Users/weichuang/Desktop/rem/remem
├── showdown@1.2.3
├── supervisor@0.6.0
└── typescript@1.6.2

=> If you wish to uninstall them at a later point (or re-install them under your
=> `nvm` Nodes), you can remove them from the system Node as follows:

     $ nvm use system
     $ npm uninstall -g a_module

=> Close and reopen your terminal to start using nvm
```

Though i Close and reopen my  terminal to start using nvm,the problem is still `-bash: nvm: command not found`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node Version Manager install - nvm command not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16904658/node-version-manager-install-nvm-command-not-found)

Answer (score 18):

Type in terminal

```
source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
source ~/.profile
source ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: what does this mean?

Answer (score 2):

My answer is based on Mac OS X but I am sure it should work for other Linux based system.

**Installing & using nvm on Mac OS X**

- Install homebrew from [here](https://brew.sh/).
- Using homebrew install nvm

  `brew update
  brew install nvm`
- Create `.nvm` directory at `~/.nvm` location.

  `mkdir ~/.nvm`
- Now if you don't have `.bash_profile` file setup for OS X terminal then please create a `.bash_profile` at the root level:

  `nano ~/.bash_profile`
- Paste below code in the `.bash_profile` and press `CTRL + O` and press enter to save `.bash_profile` file. Press `CTRL + X` to exit from editor:

  `export NVM_DIR=~/.nvm
   source $(brew --prefix nvm)/nvm.sh`
- Now either quite (`CMD + Q`) the terminal or run below command to load `.bash_profile` settings:

  `source ~/.bash_profile`
- Now run `nvm ls` command to get the list of all installed nodejs versions.