# How do I change my Node version after installing it using Homebrew?

Tags: node.js, macos, terminal, homebrew

After installing Node using Homebrew on OSX 10.11.6 I now have a copy of node installed at

> /usr/local/Cellar/node/10.7.0.

However, the version of Node that appears when I run

> $ node -v

in terminal is

> v0.12.7

I would like OSX terminal to reference the v10.07 of Node I just installed via Homebrew when I type

> $ node

**How do I change which node version that OSX terminal recognizes?**

Comment: What does `which node` say?

Comment: It doesn't return anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try using NVM. It allows you to install multiple versions of Node on your machine and switch between them conveniently:

see [NVM docs](https://github.com/creationix/nvm)

Comment: Unfortunately, I have the same problem with NVM, I also installed it using Homebrew, but terminal doesn't recognize the $ nvm command.

Comment: Have you added it to your local path?

Comment: Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16904658/node-version-manager-install-nvm-command-not-found

Comment: This was the answer!  I edited a file called .bash_profile and added 
"export PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/node/10.7.0/bin:$PATH"

to it and now it works. Thank you very much!