# Installing NVM on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS?

Tags: node.js, linux, bash, ubuntu, nvm

Trying to install NVM on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.  When I run the install script this happens:

```
ole@ole-ThinkPad-T470:~/Temp/nv$ wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.38.0/install.sh | bash
=> Downloading nvm as script to '/home/ole/.nvm'
Failed to download 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.38.0/nvm-exec'
Failed to download 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.38.0/nvm.sh'

=> nvm source string already in /home/ole/.bashrc
Failed to download 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.38.0/bash_completion'
=> bash_completion source string already in /home/ole/.bashrc
main: line 433: /home/ole/.nvm/nvm.sh: No such file or directory
=> Close and reopen your terminal to start using nvm or run the following to use it now:

export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
```

But if I wget one of the scripts that fails to download it works:

```
ole@ole-ThinkPad-T470:~/Temp/nv$ wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.38.0/nvm-exec
--2021-05-25 18:39:08--  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.38.0/nvm-exec
Resolving raw.githubusercontent.com (raw.githubusercontent.com)... 185.199.109.133, 185.199.108.133, 185.199.111.133, ...
Connecting to raw.githubusercontent.com (raw.githubusercontent.com)|185.199.109.133|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 344 [text/plain]
Saving to: ‘nvm-exec.1’

nvm-exec.1                       100%[========================================================>]     344  --.-KB/s    in 0s      

2021-05-25 18:39:08 (4.25 MB/s) - ‘nvm-exec.1’ saved [344/344]

ole@ole-ThinkPad-T470:~/Temp/nv$ ls
nvm-exec
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Do you have curl installed?

Comment: @cbr, I thought that too at first, but the script does include the ability to use wget.

Comment: I tried both curl and wget ... same result

Answer (score 8):

It looks like it's related to installing wget or curl with snap on Ubuntu:

https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/issues/2504

Here's what fixed it for me:

```
sudo snap remove curl
sudo apt install curl
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.38.0/install.sh | bash
nvm install node
```

Comment: Perfect answer thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

uninstalling snap curl and installing apt install resolved this for me as well,

```
sudo snap remove curl
sudo apt install curl
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.38.0/install.sh | bash
nvm install node
```