# Ember-cli not using global version

Tags: node.js, npm, ember.js

This might actually more npm/node than just an EmberJS question.

Simply speaking I ran `npm install -g ember-cli`. However, when I check the version using `ember --version`, it shows me

```
ember-cli: 3.10.1
node: 18.18.2
os: darwin x64
```

That is definitely not the version I installed, because if i do `npm ls -g --depth=0` to check my global packages, I get:

```
├── corepack@0.19.0
├── ember-cli@5.3.0
└── npm@10.2.0
```

To sanity check, i ran `npm uninstall -g ember-cli` and running `npm ls -g --depth=0` again  got

```
├── corepack@0.19.0
└── npm@10.2.0
```

So now, confirming that the global package is removed, I ran `ember --version` expecting the system to say ember is not installed, but instead i still get:

```
ember-cli: 3.10.1
node: 18.18.2
os: darwin x64
```

This leads me to believe there is some other installation of Ember on this computer and it's being used instead of the global version and I'd really like to just remove it - how do I find and remove it?

Useful context may be: I use `NVM` and `Brew`, although even in the past I didn't attempt to install ember with anything but the official installation direction of `npm install -g ember-cli`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a few tools in the npm ecosystem defer to local installations when installed globally, because that's usually what you want to be working with.

If you have a local `package.json`, I'd check in your current working directory and remove or upgrade ember-cli from there.

other things to check, since you mentioned nvm -- you may have multiple node/npm installations (system, and then one managed by nvm) -- it may be useful to temporarily modify your .bashrc/.zshrc and comment out the nvm lines, and then open a new shell, and see what's installed there -- if ember-cli is present, that could explain the behavior you're seeing.

Comment: Thank you very much! This led to the solution - I had these lines in my .zshrc

```export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" # This loads nvm```

Which I believe is from an old installation of nvm. I commented it out, and ran ```source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh```, as per direction in nvm. and it switched over to the latest ember-cli globally installed. 

I added the line ```source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh``` to .zshrc as directed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16904658/node-version-manager-install-nvm-command-not-found and now nvm also runs each time.